# GNU/Linux variants that could work on MacBook Pro (Retina, two GPUs)

Tags: linux-distribution, nvidia

I'm thinking about trying some GNU/Linux distros on MBP (partly because I get increasingly annoyed by OS X's long-standing bugs which probably will never be fixed, and also I wish to try "next-gen" filesystems like [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), and Windows doesn't seem to be suitable for my use cases at all…)

I've read some forums and the general consensus was that there are **some things that do not work** when running GNU/Linux. Among those I cannot live without are: Wi-Fi adapter, Thunderbolt port, display backlight control (when using NVidia GPU). The quality of NVidia drivers is also very questionable. (and I don't think I want to completely disable NVidia GPU)

So I decided to ask here, if the situation did improve since these times, and which GNU/Linux distributions are worth trying on this laptop. (And if there are any known problems, then how to solve them)

In my case, specs are:

```
(Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
CPU: 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
RAM: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB and Intel Iris Pro
```

P.S. I don't care at all about these parts (it would be even better if they do not work):
web camera, Bluetooth.

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Apple_Macbook_Pro_Retina - a guide for gentoo linux. nvidia proprietary video drivers is decent. It could handle optimus switching, see readme: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/358.16/README/randr14.html